# Is there any way to prevent throwing errors on the chrome console if anything goes wrong?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, error-handling, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to prevent throwing errors on the chrome console if anything goes wrong?
I am fetching some data from an API, I want that whenever the user requested data will not exist in the API it just ignore and will not throw red errors on the console, I tried `try-catch but that doesn't work for me...
Code:

```
fetch('https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/'+def)
      .then(res =>{
        if(res.ok){
          return res.json()}
          else {
            speak(`i don\'t know exactly what is ${def}`)
```

error:
[image]

Comment: Are you calling `.catch` on the promise object? Also the error, mentioning reading `0` does not seem to come from the code you posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.catch(err => setTimeout(() => console.clear()))
```

...should do it. The `setTimeout` bit is necessary. It needs to be placed at the end of the execution queue.

See it working:

```js
fetch('//non-existent-url')
  .catch(err => setTimeout(() => console.clear()))
```

Comment: Are you saying I shouldn't see anything in console if I go `fetch('stuff').catch(void 0)`?

Comment: Without that leading `.`, yes. :-) But I'm intrigued to see that I appear to be wrong! Your `fetch('//non-existent-url')` example causes a log.

Comment: Side note: I'm surprised to find that passing no second argument to `setTimeout` seems to lead to [unspecified behavior](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps). I would have assumed there'd be a default, but I don't see one in the steps. Is it elsewhere in the spec do you know?

Comment: My Chrome (`Version 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit)
`) throws two errors on that: A) `GET https://non-existent-url/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED;` B) `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch at ...`

Comment: Yeah, LOL, I just edited that comment. `fetch('stuff')` didn't do that (there was no HTTP call, it failed earlier), but Chrome reports failed HTTP calls to the console (your `fetch('//non-existent-url')` example) -- which is exactly what the question was asking about.

Comment: @TJ, ref "*Is it elsewhere in the spec do you know?*". Sorry, can't point to any specs ref `fetch` (or `XHR`, for that matter). My knowledge is purely empirical on this one. I'll dig, though.

Comment: The question was about `setTimeout`, not `fetch` or `XHR`. You have no second argument to `setTimeout` above, but [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps) doesn't seem to allow that, so it's not clear to me what timeout is applied. (And that surprises me, I would have thought the spec would cover that.) It's just idle curiousity... :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239569/discussion-between-tao-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: `.catch(err => setTimeout(() => console.clear()))
` this helped me